# Short honking noise coming from chassis a few minutes after turning 2001 Silverado off

Tags: chevrolet, noise, silverado

It is very consistent. After even a few minutes of city driving I turn the engine off, and maybe 1-2 minutes later a short beep, almost like a fart, comes from underneath the body. It happens only once. I would like to know what might be causing this.

Comment: It’s the cat... :). Well, more likely a suspension joint that is not properly tightened though - had any work done recently?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!